# Count of open sockets to the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to check open socket connection count to the database.

Is there any way to get the number of open sockets to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This query will give you the current number of client connections using TCP/IP.  Of course there are other things that use sockets on the server.

```
select count(*) connections
from sys.dm_exec_connections
where net_transport = 'TCP'
```

You can see all the sockets usage on the server using the [netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) command.